# Search form with Category and Sub Category

Tags: search, cms, link-category

How to create WP Search Form with Category and Sub category 
for illustration a search form (for search title Book=title post) 
With condition By Keyword, By All Category and Sub Category selected 
Where, Sub Category (CD, PDF, EPub,...) 
I Look Around for a Week but unsuccessful,   
Help me , Please ...
=> [For My Client blog for CMS Ebook](http://penerbit-ebook.com)

**I Have modified my form like This :**

```
<?php $media = array(
 'hierarchical'       => 1,
 'parent'             => get_cat_id('Media'),
 'show_option_none'   => ('All Media'),
 'hide_empty'   => 0  ); 
?>

<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=All Category'); ?>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories($media); ?>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**How to Create Function or modified form again ? Without Plugin...**
For a detailed answer I am very grateful !!!

Answer (score 3):

First you have to give your dropdown names so:

```
<?php $media = array(
 'name'               => 'subcat',
 'hierarchical'       => 1,
 'parent'             => get_cat_id('Media'),
 'show_option_none'   => ('All Media'),
 'hide_empty'   => 0  ); 
?>

<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('name=maincat&show_option_none=All Category'); ?>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories($media); ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="my_search" name="my_search" value="c_search" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Then create you search filter

```
// Define search filter
function search_filter( $query ) {
    // only modify your custom search query.
    if ( $query->is_search &&  $_post['my_search'] == "c_search") {
        $args = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $_post['maincat']),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $_post['subcat']),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $args);
    }
    return $query;
}

// The hook needed to search_filter
add_filter( 'the_search_query','search_filter');
```

Comment: Glad i could help